# Is it possibile to send NaN value to a param to bypass (PHP)?

Tags: web-application, php

is it possibile to bypass some check like this:

```
$amount = (int)$_REQUEST['amount'];
if (!($amount >= 10)) {
   // authorize
}
```

by sending a NaN value to `amount` param?
like: `https://www.site.com/?amount?<NaN>`

and if it is, how can I pass this value?

Because as Wikipedia show:
[image]

Theoretically, this should work but I can't figure out any way to "assign" a NaN value in order to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the code is incomplete, there are a few things that stand out...

That if statement logic is terrible `if not ($amount is greater than 9) == true` is a werid way to write `if ($amount <= 9)`. As the comparison uses the double compare you could potentially have performed type juggling. However $amount is cast to int making this a non issue. Also by assigning it to a temporary value via an int cast further use will contain the same number, however if the check uses $amount and the authorization code uses `$_GET['amount']` or `$_REQUEST['amount']` you could bypass the check and perform SQL in a later step.

Sometimes you can break PHP logic by making the variable an array, ie: `https://www.site.com/?amount[]=1` however, this doesn't work against a cast to int. In this case it looks like you can just straight up authorize by setting the value to something less than 10. ie:

- https://www.site.com/?amount=0
- https://www.site.com/?amount=BBBB

This kinda feels like homework, so maybe post the code and objective in full?

Comment: sorry if I was inactive, unfortunately, I can't post the code here because the code refers to a CTF I think the writeup was not published yet. however thanks for your help, it was still helpful, I'll mark this as an answer!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help